# How to set a fixed field in mongoengine/pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, field, mongoengine

I'd like to set for the `ProofModel` subclasses to have the `type_` field set and immutable.

```
class ProofType(Enum):
    JWS = "RsaVerificationKey2018"
    HASH = "Sha2"


class ProofModel(EmbeddedDocument):

    type_ = EnumField(ProofType, required=True)
    created = DateTimeField(default=datetime.now(), required=True)

    meta = {"allow_inheritance": True}


class JwsProofModel(ProofModel):

    type_ = EnumField(ProofType, default=ProofType.JWS)
    jws = StringField(required=True)


class ShaProofModel(ProofModel):

    type_ = EnumField(ProofType, default=ProofType.HASH)
    hash_ = StringField(required=True)
```

I could leave it as above but my need is to limit the ability to create a (for example) `JwsProofModel` having the `type_` specified when instantiated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see 2 options:

1)
(not released yet) You can abuse the `choices` parameter on the EnumField constructor to limit the allowed value to just 1 value.

```
class JwsProofModel(ProofModel):
    type_ = EnumField(ProofType, default=ProofType.JWS, choices=[ProofType.JWS])
    jws = StringField(required=True)
```

This feature is only available on the development version (future 0.23.2) but it should get released shortly

2)
As a workaround, use the custom per-field validation feature ([doc](https://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/validation.html#custom-validation))

```
def is_jws(value):
    if value != ProofType.JWS:
        raise ValidationError("wrong value")

class JwsProofModel(Document):
    type_ = EnumField(ProofType, default=ProofType.JWS, validation=is_jws)
```

Comment: it throws `ValueError: 'choices' can't be set on EnumField, it is implicitly set as the enum class`

Comment: Right, as I said, it's only available on development version (latest master) but it will be released shortly

Comment: I've added an alternative in the post, not the most elegant but it should do the trick until EnumField choices feature gets released